# Laptop Freezes until I either insert or remove charger

Tags: windows-10, freeze, power, charger, usb-c

I have an odd bug and I'm not sure what might be causing it. I have a 15.6" Xiaomi Notebook Pro with a USB-C charger.

Every so often, my laptop screen freezes. Music still plays in the background and I assume other processes are also running. Only, I can't move my mouse or make any input. I can solve this by either inserting the USB-C charger if it's not already inserted, or taking out the charger if it is inserted. Then everything goes back to working as intended.

The nature of the solution leads me to believe that this is some power issue but I'm not quite sure how I would go about fixing it permanently.

Comment: It looks like your laptop has a problem with power management, with one of intermediate states. Try to change power management settings, make them more aggressive, or less aggressive.

Comment: I have the same problem and it also works to plug in an HDMI monitor and unplug it. Then the commands I gave while the screen was frozen replay in fast-forward until it's all caught up. Mine is a Dell G7.